# Filter the data shown in table based on @input value in angular

Tags: angular

I have a child component which receives a search data based on which i have to display/filter the data shown in the table

my tempelate looks as below -

```
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Grade</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor = "let stud of student$|async">
            <tr *ngIf="searchData===stud.firstName">
                <td>{{stud.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{stud.grade}}</td>
            </tr> 
        </ng-container>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my component is as below

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {GetvalidationService} from '../_services/getvalidation.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface student {
  userId:number,
  firstName:string,
  grade:string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() searchData : string;
  
  constructor(private service:GetvalidationService) { }
  student$:Observable<student[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStudentData();
  }
  
  //async pipe is being used to subscribe to the observable 
  getStudentData(){
     this.student$ = this.service.getStudentData().pipe(map(res=>this.getData(res)))  
     
  }

  //if we have more fields we can select specific field and also operate on it
  getData(res){
    let student : student[] = []
    res.data.users.forEach(element => {
      let stud = {} as student;
      stud.firstName = element.firstName,
      stud.grade = element.grade
      stud.userId = element.userId
      student.push(stud)
    });

    return student;
  }
}
```

and I'm passing the search data from parent component to the child component using @input ,so how can i implement the search in it,I gave a try with making api call with search data,but is there any way that i can do it on the client side itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

searchData$ subject (when searchData is entered passed it to the subject)

filteredStudentData$ = combine the student data and apply the filter with searchData$

And all this should be defined in the parent component. The child component (table) should only receive students and not have any logic.